# How will the iOS app know it has to register for APNS or not?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I know that the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken` gets called when your app successfully registers for Push Notifications and you get your device token.

As per Apple Documentation *The device token is provided to you by your client app, which receives the token **after registering itself** with the remote notification service.*

I want to know how will an app know if **HAS to register** itself for remote notification services or not on launch.

Comment: on launch pop up to allow push notification will show.

Comment: Your app either needs to register for remote notification or it doesn't need to. It depends on your app requirement. If you can say the reason for you to find out if the app **has to register** itself for remote notification, we can help you out better.

Comment: @ebby94 Only you have followed my question! The only reason for me to find out if the app **has to register** itself **or not** for remote notifications is to get one step deeper than the  otherwise starting point - i.e. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been down-voted. It'll be nicer If the person who did it, explains why he/she felt this was an invalid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up myself - the ***"Initial point"*** is setting the **PushNotifications Enabled** in your provisioning profile in developer portal that fires off the indication to **Register** your app for Remote Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement push notification you need to write the following in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
    UIUserNotificationType type=(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings=[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:type categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Apart from that you need to create apns development certificate and respective provisioning profiles where push notification service is enabled . When you build your app in a device with those provisioning profiles then the device will understand that this app has push notification enabled service and the device will provide an alert Would you like to get push notification? 
If user press ok then only  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is fired and developer  can get deviceToken.

Comment: I think OP just wants to know if his app **has to register** for push notification in his code and not **how to register** for push notification.

Comment: As per @Reshmi's explanation, can we conclude that if we have built an app with the APNS certificates and Provisioning Profile, **That's what tells my app to register** to remote notifications?